# how to create captcha in identityServer3 login pages

Tags: captcha, recaptcha, identityserver3

I want to use captcha in my login Pages in identityServer3, How do i that?
Is there a sample source ?
I Try To Use Google reCaptcha but it dose not work.
Please Help Me

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it without using IViewService

Add recaptcha scripts to the Templates/_layout.html head tag

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

Add snippet to login screen page in Templates/_login.html, with added **name="g-recaptcha-response"**
attribute

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" name="g-recaptcha-response" data-sitekey="your sitekey"></div>
```

Add CspOptions to the Startup Class to allow google script

```cs
CspOptions = new CspOptions
{
    Enabled = true,
    FontSrc = "'self' data: fonts.gstatic.com",
    StyleSrc = "'self' 'unsafe-inline' fonts.googleapis.com",
    ScriptSrc = "'self' https://www.google.com https://www.gstatic.com; object-src 'self'",
    FrameSrc = "https://www.google.com"
}
```

Inject `OwinEnvironmentService` to the UserService class - This will allow you to grab the token from the reCaptcha snippet

```cs
private readonly OwinEnvironmentService _environmentService;

public UserService(OwinEnvironmentService environmentService)
{
    _environmentService = environmentService;
}
```

At AuthenticateLocalAsync, grab the token and verify it

```cs
var gReCaptchaResponse = _environmentService.GetLoginInput("g-recaptcha-response");
var client = new RestClient("https://www.google.com");
var request = new RestRequest("recaptcha/api/siteverify", Method.POST) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
request.AddParameter("secret", "YOUR SECRET");
request.AddParameter("response", gReCaptchaResponse);
var response = client.Execute(request);
var verficationStatus = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GReCaptcha>(response.Content);

if(!verficationStatus.Success)
{
    Logger.Warn("Captcha invalid");
    context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult("Please verify that you are not a robot");
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

GetLoginInput(*form input name*) extension
(credit to martinip86 from answer in [Github](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/3113)

```cs
public static string GetLoginInput(this OwinEnvironmentService environmentService, string fieldName)
{
    const string body = "owin.RequestBody";
    if (!environmentService.Environment.Keys.Contains(body))
        return null;

    var owinFormData = environmentService.Environment[body] as System.IO.Stream;
    if (owinFormData == null)
        return null;

    var formData = string.Empty;
    using (var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(owinFormData))
    {
        formData = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(formData))
        return null;

    var formDataParsed = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(formData);
    return formDataParsed[fieldName];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The better question is `how to customize the login screen?`
see [the documentation on customizing views](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/customizingViews.html)

> The views in IdentityServer can be customized in one of two ways: 1)
>   Customize the HTML templates provided by the DefaultViewService, or if
>   more control is needed 2) define a custom IViewService

Implement a custom `IViewService` to [change the full layout](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/customizingViews.html).
Also if you want to change only the login page, add your custom html that implements the same angular logic as the [existing login page](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Services/DefaultViewService/PageAssets/login.html) and adding it to a folder named `templates` with a file name of `_login.html`. 
If you want to modify the [layout](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Services/DefaultViewService/PageAssets/layout.html) (the headers) then you need to do the same this time naming the file `_Layout.html`.
This is all expalined in the [documentation](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/DefaultViewService.html), with the above listed as "Replacing partial views".